# Can I tell EF6 to not try and insert a value into a column if it's null and there's a default?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following class:

```
public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    ...
    public string QuestionUId { get; set; }
}

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Question] (
    [QuestionId] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    ...
    [QuestionUId] CHAR(6) DEFAULT (right(newid(),(6))) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Question] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([QuestionId] ASC)
);
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Question_QuestionUId_IX]
    ON [dbo].[Question]([QuestionUId] ASC);
```

When I insert a new record then QuestionId has a value of zero and when the record gets inserted it is assigned a new value by the identity column of the database. At this time the QuestionUId is null so when the record gets added it gets a value of null instead of what I would like which is the default value.

Is there some way in the mapping that I could make the QuestionUId let the database assign the value rather than have it insert a value of null for new records that are added:

```
public QuestionMap()
{
    // Primary Key
    this.HasKey(t => t.QuestionId);

    // Properties
    this.Property(t => t.Text).HasMaxLength(4000);

    // Table & Column Mappings
    this.ToTable("Question");
    this.Property(t => t.QuestionId).HasColumnName("QuestionId");
    this.Property(t => t.QuestionUId).HasColumnName("QuestionUId");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

EF currently does not support database default values for updatable columns. Database default value is applied only when the column is not used in the insert statement but EF always sends all columns in insert statements. The only option to avoid sending column in insert statement is to mark it with database generated option (`Identity` or `Computed`). Those will be handled by database and you will not be able to change their value in your application. Integer primary key is automatically set as `Identity`.

So if you only want to use default value from database and you never plan to set it or change it in your application you can also mark the column as `Identity` with:

```
this.Property(t => t.QuestionUId)
    .HasColumnName("QuestionUId") // btw. this is not necessary because the name is same as the property
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

If you want to modify or set the value in your application as well you cannot use database generation and you must move your default value generation to your application. Database default will never be used.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the QuestionUId column NOT NULL in the database.

Annotate the QuestionUId property as computed:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
```

This can also be done in the EF designer, assuming you are updating model from database as opposed to using code first.

More importantly:

1. Why do you need a second unique identifier?
2. Why do you think the last 6 chars of NEWID() will always be unique?

This smells like an XYProblem :)